# Django select objects where field is in range

Tags: python, django

I have a django model called `MyModel` which has two fields:

```py
a = models.IntegerField(...)
b = models.DateTimeField(...)
```

I would like to select all of the `MyModel`s which have an `a` value between `0` and `10`. For example:

```py
results = [obj for obj in MyModel.objects.all() if 0 <= obj.a <= 10]
```

This works, but requires looping through every row in Python and is not efficient whatsoever.

As an extension to this, how would I perform a similar query for field `b`, selecting every object which has time within the last 15 minutes. This is how I would write the query in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM appname_mymodel WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, b, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 15;
```

I would like a python + django way of writing this query, if possible.

Comment: @IainShelvington It points to the `range` [API reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) which was very helpful, thanks! I'll post an answer to this question with code examples for both of my questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) is the API reference for 'Field Lookups' which are "how you specify the meat of an SQL WHERE clause".

For specifically the questions that I asked:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

a_results = MyModel.objects.filter(a__range = (0, 10))
b_results = MyModel.objects.filter(b__gt = datetime.now() - timedelta(mintues = 15))
```